# How to pass map attribute to apex controller

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, controller, lightning

I am in a complex situation here. I want to pass a map attribute defined lightning component(which is a map of maps as shown below) to apex controller.

> Map Attributes

```
<aura:attribute name="settingsFieldMap" type="Map" default="{}"/> <!-- Map of maps with key as a custom object and value as the map below(fieldValuesMap): -->
<aura:attribute name="fieldValuesMap" type="Map" default="{}"/> <!--this is a map of String to String-->
```

> like

```
settingsFieldMap[key]=fieldValuesMap;
```

It shows me all values properly when I iterate throug it in component controller, but when I pass it in Apex controller, it shows null.

> definition of Apex controller method:

```
public static void updateEditedValues(Map<customObject__c, Map<String, String>> settingsFieldMap)
```

Comment: are you getting any errors in java script console or debug logs

Comment: Doesn't show any error in console or debug logs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out better way to pass data rather than this complex logic. Hence, closing it.

NOTE: I used a list of list custom settings records , stringified them, de-serialised them in apex and then used them. Related question to this was:

[How to pass LIST custom setting list(array) from client side to server side controller in lightning?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149476/how-to-pass-list-custom-setting-listarray-from-client-side-to-server-side-cont)

Comment: Now I am in a situation where I have to pass map, list won't do. This time it is map of String to String. Please help!

Comment: Had to pass again using JSON